# Which script editor can code-color hex color values?

Tags: editor, colors

I frequently work with lots of hexadecimal color values in my programs. Is there a script editor that can code-color the color values, based upon the colors they describe? .. (eg #FF0000 should be colored RED and 0x00FF00 should be colored GREEN)

Answer (score 0):

The text editor [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) has since version 20.00 the CSS color tooltip feature which is described as follows by IDM Computer Solutions, Inc.

- Hovering cursor over a supported color definition causes a color "swatch" to be displayed. Users can CTRL+CLICK on "swatch" to invoke OS color picker to select a new color.
- "Display CSS color tooltips" Configuration option added under Advanced -> Configuration -> Editor Display -> Miscellaneous
- Detects and supports colors defined in the following formats:

  - Hex RGB
  - Functional notation RGB
  - RGBA
  - HSL
  - HSLA
- Tooltips supported in the following file types:

  - HTML
  - CSS
  - Javascript
  - PHP
  - Perl
  - Python
  - Ruby

This feature does not syntax highlight the color value itself in the text file with the color according to the value. But it displays the color in a rectangle below the mouse pointer when mouse pointer is positioned over a color value in one of the supported formats.

So this feature of UltraEdit is not exactly what have been asked for, but is perhaps nevertheless very helpful for you.

In my point of view it does not really make sense to syntax highlight the color value itself in the color according to the value as this results most likely quite often in not visible or hard to see values. For example think about color value white with using white as text background color. Lots of combinations of text and background colors make the text very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

**SynWrite** editor can do it. `#RRGGBB` or `rgb(rr, gg, bb)` fragments are hilited.

[image: Colors]